# creating Rich Text Editor using new InputFormTextBox() SharePoint 2007

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007, rte, cewp

I know this probably an easy question to answer, or at least I'm hoping it is.  I have a CEWP (Content Editor Web Part) that I'm trying to use custom code to create an input field for access to update a list.  I would like the input to be a Rich Text Editor.  I've tried writing the following in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    user = getUserAccountInfo();
    username = user.PreferredName;

    InputFormTextBox textbox = new InputFormTextBox();
    textbox.ID = "inputFormTextBox1";
    textbox.TextMode = TextBoxTextMode.MultiLine;
    textbox.rows = 6;
    textbox.columns = 75;
});
```

I get an error message of needing a semicolon ';' at the line declaring the InputFormTextBox.  It looks valid to me.  I am then calling the text values from the box, and using SPServices UpdateListItems.

Comment: This question should in sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, I guess a lot of the problem is that I'm trying to mix JavaScript with C#.  I would like to do it just in JavaScript.  Is it possible?